# Is it possible to construct Euclidean function from a Euclidean Domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that we have a Euclidean Domain as a ring, but we are not given a Euclidean function. We know that the ring is a Euclidean Domain. We have an oracle for +, . and whether a/b. Can we construct a computable function v, that will satisfy the definision of a Euclidean function?

Comment: This [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68538/is-there-a-division-algorithm-for-any-euclidean-domain) and its answer seem to answer your question in negative.